# Is it safe to use ComboBox.DisplayMember without data binding?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I've always understood that [DisplayMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember.aspx) and ValueMember are only supposed to be used when databinding a ComboBox using its DataSource property.

But in some code I'm maintaing I've noticed that using a ComboBox' `DisplayMember` property *does* work without databinding. Setting the property determines what is shown in the combobox. Setting `ValueMember` does not seem to work though (it does not set `SelectedValue`).

My question is: is it safe to use this behavior? Or is there a risk the behavior may change in upcoming versions of .NET?

*I know you'd normally override the `ToString` method. In the real code, the MyType class is not as simple as in my example. I'm not sure if it would be safe to override its `ToString` method.*

---

A small sample to show this behavior.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

internal class Program {
    public class MyType {
        public string MyText { get; set; }
        public string MyValue { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyForm : Form {
        private readonly ComboBox _myComboBox;

        public MyForm() {
            _myComboBox = new ComboBox {DisplayMember = "MyText", ValueMember = "MyValue"};
            _myComboBox.Items.Add(new MyType {MyText = "First item", MyValue = "1"});
            _myComboBox.Items.Add(new MyType {MyText = "Second item", MyValue = "2"});
            _myComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += _myComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged;
            Controls.Add(_myComboBox);
        }

        private void _myComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            var cb = (ComboBox) sender;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(
                "Index: {0}, SelectedValue: {1}", cb.SelectedIndex, cb.SelectedValue);
        }
    }

    private static void Main() {
        Application.Run(new MyForm());
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's surprising that `DataMember` even works. Why not use `DataSource`?

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23071025/is-it-a-bad-idea-to-use-the-combobox-displaymember-valuemember-properties