# Is it a bad idea to use the comboBox.DisplayMember & ValueMember properties?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm adding a combobox to a WinForms application, I came across the DisplayMember & ValueMember properties.  Their functionality is exactly what I need in my application, but I'm not sure I like the way they work.

```
comboBox.Items.Add(myObj);
comboBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
comboBox.ValueMember = "Id";
```

In the code above my object is the actual "Item", and it's name & Id properties will be used for displayed text & selected value respectively.  The thing I'm unsure of is the hard coded "Name" & "Id" being passed into those properties.  That is something not checked at compile time.  So, if I ever changed my object.Name property to object.FullName, this code would break at runtime.

I've thought about getting the property name dynamically (as asked here: [get name of a variable or parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801624/get-name-of-a-variable-or-parameter)), but that feels very wrong.

So, is it ill-advised to use these properties?  If so, what is the recommended way to store my object as the combobox item?

Comment: Not ill-advised.  Its exactly how they were designed to be used.

Comment: Ok. What about the fact that this will not be checked at compile time?  Am I making that out to be a bigger problem than it really is?

Comment: No, that is a valid concern. I know that i've seen some libraries that will allow you to do compile time checks, but the combobox control has been around for such a long time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is perfectly fine to use them.

For your concern of compile-time checks: in the next version of C# there is a `nameof` operator, comparable to the `typeof` there is now already.

You could use it like this:

```
comboBox.DisplayMember = nameof(obj.Name);
```

There are [solutions](http://joelabrahamsson.com/getting-property-and-method-names-using-static-reflection-in-c/) already there to get a similar result.

Comment: I wish I had that available to me.  I would make it very clean.  Thanks!

Comment: Maybe [this](http://joelabrahamsson.com/getting-property-and-method-names-using-static-reflection-in-c/) is useful.

Comment: Actually, it's the next version of C#, not of .NET, that will introduce the `nameof` operator... This is just a compile-time thing, the runtime has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 2):

This sort of loose-coupling between model/viewmodel and view is actually becoming more and more common. XAML's binding (used in WPF, Silverlight, Windows Phone, etc) works in a very similar fashion. There are techniques you can use to force the XAML designers to provide some feedback (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602274.aspx), but these don't break the compile. Accept it!